# Mutual SSL handshake failure during CertificateVerify step

Tags: java, security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

We have a client app that is trying to connect to a server using mutual SSL (Java 1.8.0_181). Through the logs gathered using the `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` option and reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html, it appears:

- the keystore and truststore are being initialized correctly (appropriate `found key for : 20200724101630-mybox-int` entry for the keystore and `adding as trusted cert: Subject: CN=myOrgCN, OU=myOrgOU, O=myOrgO, C=BE, DC=myOrg, DC=com` entry for the truststore)
- Successful ClientHello message
- Successful ServerHello message where they agree on a cipher (`TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384`)
- Certificate match (`Found trusted certificate: Issuer: CN=myOrgCN, OU=myOrgOU, O=myOrgO, C=BE, DC=myOrg, DC=com` in the logs)
- Successful ServerHelloDone message
- Matching cert found (`matching alias: 20200724101630-mybox-int` in the logs)
- Successful ECDHClientKeyExchange message
- Failed CertificateVerify message

The failed CertificateVerify message doesn't contain much info, just an EOF/disconnection. From what I can tell the previous steps worked with no issue? Does anyone have any advice?

**client.log:**

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
*** Certificate chain
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
*** CertificateRequest
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 183, 178, 125, 32, 33, 188, 107, 247, 199, 129, 51, 106, 171, 247, 13, 191, 230, 107, 60, 229, 194, 177, 104, 246, 108, 193, 41, 123, 152, 179, 124, 106, 157, 241, 162, 155, 218, 176, 160, 1, 149, 177, 167, 106, 119, 155, 83, 30, 47, 223, 217, 177, 55, 81, 163, 131, 186, 38, 204, 146, 236, 102, 246, 84 }
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4829
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: BE 88 D0 99 DB BE B4 63   79 F6 B1 FE B1 48 27 9A  .......cy....H'.
0010: 32 7B 14 58 D9 BE 42 8E   74 0F 6B CC C9 7A 4A B0  2..X..B.t.k..zJ.
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 5F 40 45 44 68 1D 74 41   2E 2B 3B 53 EC 3C 12 68  _@EDh.tA.+;S.<.h
0010: B9 47 00 87 B9 1D 2D E3   83 2A 5F 24 D0 4B 3F 77  .G....-..*_$.K?w
Server Nonce:
0000: 5F 40 45 44 F8 73 BB 6E   F2 6F AF 22 E2 36 F7 4E  _@ED.s.n.o.".6.N
0010: 6D 14 1E D5 FE EC 7A C3   57 0B A6 1A 43 A0 E8 87  m.....z.W...C...
Master Secret:
0000: 71 35 29 46 00 D8 85 63   4B 2F 57 B4 1C B6 EA 4A  q5)F...cK/W....J
0010: D9 0D 90 3F B1 52 FE BD   9A 13 26 9C 75 29 8A 99  ...?.R....&.u)..
0020: B1 4C 2D C2 21 8D 54 23   18 69 EE 17 F3 4D 00 84  .L-.!.T#.i...M..
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: E2 13 DC 30 B9 62 82 E2   1B 3B EA 3F F2 4D D0 33  ...0.b...;.?.M.3
0010: 59 09 A3 3B 2E 37 DA 53   FA 84 8E 95 90 A6 24 D7  Y..;.7.S......$.
0020: 04 60 29 A9 B8 AA E5 6E   09 3E C9 CC 61 42 71 50  .`)....n.>..aBqP
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 7C EF 07 AB 10 D1 99 C0   07 B4 6E 74 0C A1 98 C6  ..........nt....
0010: 7F E7 2E 6B 8B BB B4 1D   B5 5F E4 78 0F 8E 59 EB  ...k....._.x..Y.
0020: 94 88 C9 C5 C2 35 EC AF   26 C8 65 34 EA DC FC 3D  .....5..&.e4...=
Client write key:
0000: A0 D0 9A E0 2F 16 BC E5   CA F9 B2 6D D2 C0 D2 7C  ..../......m....
0010: CD 69 FF A0 EF B4 02 8D   E7 20 94 A5 8A 6A DB A0  .i....... ...j..
Server write key:
0000: 8E 43 C9 6C 93 96 7C 44   41 3C 57 80 5F 70 33 DE  .C.l...DA<W._p3.
0010: 77 AF 3C A6 3D 3A CB D4   A9 AA BF 4C 06 80 3C B7  w.<.=:.....L..<.
... no IV derived for this protocol
*** CertificateVerify
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 264
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 145, 206, 234, 159, 33, 65, 40, 99, 192, 197, 143, 244 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 96
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
main, received EOFException: error
main, Exception while waiting for close javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 80
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
main, called closeSocket()
java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

**To Run:**

`java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="mykeystore.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypassword SSLPoke mydomain.local.int 13309`

**Source code:**

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;

/** Establish a SSL connection to a host and port, writes a byte and
 * prints the response. See
 * http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+to+SSL+services
 */
public class SSLPoke {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: "+SSLPoke.class.getName()+" <host> <port>");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

            InputStream in = sslsocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = sslsocket.getOutputStream();

            // Write a test byte to get a reaction :)
            out.write(1);

            while (in.available() > 0) {
                System.out.print(in.read());
            }
            System.out.println("Successfully connected");

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The peer closed the connection before the localhost failed the certificate. You need to investigate that first. The log contains a `CertificateRequest` but the localhost didn't send one. That means that the localhost didn't have a certificate that matches what the server specified in the request, or maybe didn't really have one at all.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne: OP has clearly redacted the log hugely, but TLS(1.2) client _cannot_ send CertificateVerify without having (selected and) sent a certificate (in Certificate message, before the ClientKeyExchange). tim: the disconnect isn't necessarily for the CertVerify; the entire flight (Certificate, ClientKX, CertVerify, CCS, Finished) is sent together and any of them _could_ have caused the disconnect. Although if a decent server doesn't like the cert(s) it should give a specific alert, not a disconnect. Ask the server's admin(s) what it logged about (or at the time of) the error.